# Autocomplete with a foreign key using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an application dealing with Donations from Houses for a Church. I would like it so when a donation comes in to the Church, someone will type in a textbox the address but as there will be a lot of homes, I want an autocomplete box to make it easier.

Here are my models:

```
 public class Donation
{
    [Key]
    public int DonationId { get; set; }

    public string TypeOfDonation { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Church")]
    public int ChurchId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("House")]
    public int HouseId{ get; set; }

    public virtual Church Church { get; set; }
    public virtual House House { get; set; }

}

public class House
{
    [Key]
    public int HouseNumber { get; set; }

    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }

}
```

I think I am doing something wrong in my controller method:

```
public JsonResult GetAddress(string term)
    {
        var items = db.Houses
            .Where(x => x.AddressLine1.Contains(term))
            .Select(x => new { Label = x.HouseNumber, Value = x.AddressLine1 })
            .Take(10);

        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Or my jQuery:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.House.HouseNumber, "Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.House.HouseNumber, new { id = "HouseNumber" })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.House.HouseNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

$('#Address').autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetAddress", "DonationsController")',
        { term: request.term },
        function(data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.Label,
                    value: item.Value
                }
            }));
        });
},
minLength: 2
})
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**
[image: Problem]

Comment: Please explain. What is the problem?

Comment: My problem is that nothing loads up when I type an address that should be in the database @buffjape

Comment: Have you looked at the request/response cycle in a browser's network inspector tools? Can you update the question with information on what jquery library you are using? (looks like jquery ui) Have you attached a debugger to the server side and stepped through there?

Comment: @Charlie I've added the picture of when I press f12 and monitor what is going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the problem.

When creating URLs in MVC, you should not include the word "Controller", even though the controller class is called `DonationsController`

Change it to

```
  $.get('@Url.Action("GetAddress", "Donations")',
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created an autocomplete with JQuery UI this example could help.

jQuery

```
$("#txtCode").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ProductAutocompleteByCode", "Products")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    codigo: $("#txtCode").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var parsedData = $.map(data, function (n, i) {
                        return { label: n.Code, value: n.Id };
                    });
                    response(parsedData);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Controller

```
 public JsonResult ProductAutocompleteByCode(string code)
    {
        var products = Json(db.Products.Where(p => p.code.Contains(code)).Select(p => new ProductDTO { Id = p.id, Code = p.code, Name = p.name, Price= p.price }));

        return Json(products.Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```